# Parse-server cloud code - previously working queries all return undefined errors

Tags: heroku, parse-cloud-code, parse-server

I moved my Parse app to Heroku and MongoLab. Everything is working fine except for my cloud code queries. Whichever query I call, the error block gets called, and the error object is undefined.

Example query:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeDelete("Project", function(request, response) {

    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

    var projectId = request.object.id;

    var Project = Parse.Object.extend("Project");    
    var query = new Parse.Query(Project);

        query.get(projectId, {
            success: function(project) {

               //do some stuff with project
                response.success("Success!"); 

            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log("Error Querying Deleted Project");
                response.error("Error!"); 
            }

        });

});
```

It's not just this query, other queries are not working either. These queries were working when hosted on Parse.com. I didn't change them.

**Edit:**

So I changed my syntax from `error: function(error)` to `error: function(model, error)` and I ended up getting an error, which I researched a little and now I'm at the point where I realize that my Project class (which I am trying to manipulate above) never receives any kind of permission. There's no Role or ACL attached to it.

Here's how I create my Role:

```
var roleName = "hasSound_" + ident;
var projectRole = new Parse.Role(roleName, new Parse.ACL());
projectRole.getUsers().add(creator); 

return projectRole.save().then(function(role) {

    var acl = new Parse.ACL();
    acl.setReadAccess(role, true); //give read access to Role
    acl.setWriteAccess(role, true); //give write access to Role

    project.setACL(acl);            
    project.save();

  });
```

And here's the bad request I'm getting when trying to create the Parse.Role:

`Mar 04 14:39:32 ancient-lake-41070 heroku/router:  at=info method=POST path="/parse/classes/_Role" host=ancient-lake-41070.herokuapp.com request_id=82af3849-842a-406f-8a4b-5f573e08a1e1 fwd="54.145.36.110" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=400 bytes=578`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is probably that you shouldn't use `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey()` with parse server. Instead you should set the master key in the query like this `query.get(projectId, {useMasterKey: true, success: fun...}}`.

That said it is strange that the error object was null. Should have had the message `unauthorized`.

EDIT: Try this syntax for your error function: `error: function(model, error) { console.log(error); }`

Comment: I thought it would have something to do with `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey()` too, but no luck. Still failing and the error object is still undefined.

Comment: Do you get the error object if you use this syntax instead? `error: function(model, error) { console.log(error); }`

Comment: I edited my answer, doing that gave me an "unable to access Parse API" error, which I fixed and now I have new issues.

Comment: You should probably create a new question for this issue. Feel free to link to it here. Make sure that you include the error you get from the save() method. Also, you should probably have `return project.save();` instead of just `project.save()`.